# Intuitive meaning of null-homotopic map between sphere an torus.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, intuition

I am given an exercise where I have to show that every continuous map from $S^2$ to $T^2$ is null-homotopic. I don't really understand what is the implication of this result intuitively.

Comment: @postmortes, thank you, I think I understand

Comment: Hint: note that since $T^2=S^1\times S^1$ and $\pi_k(X\times Y)\cong \pi_k(X) \times \pi_k(Y)$, it suffices to show $\pi_2(S^1)=0$.